# Having flashing elements in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So, I want my login portal page to have a flashing underscore after the title. All the HTML is fine, it's getting a form of delay in between the style being changed in the JavaScript. I have tried doing this:

```
const underscore = document.getElementById('flashingUnderscore');
function flash() {
    while (true) {
        underscore.style.display = 'none';
        window.setTimeout(dump,1000);
        underscore.style.display = 'block';
        window.setTimeout(dump,1000);
    };
};
function dump() {
    return;
}
```

But this doesn't work, *evidently*. So I'm turning to the community for ideas as I'm kind of stumped. [Image of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClOfF.png)

Comment: without your `HTML` code we can't give you suitable solutions. Kindly, edit your post by adding the equivalent `HTML`. And you can use only `CSS` to achieve your goal.

Comment: You may want to consider using CSS animation rather than an infinite loop. See for example [How to make blinking/flashing text with CSS 3?](//stackoverflow.com/q/16344354)

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript, you might find [How to make a text flash in html/javascript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8360130) interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `setTimeout`, consider using `setInterval` so you can avoid the loop. You can then do something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    underscore.style.display = underscore.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This throws a Syntax Error: Invalid or Unexpected token
Edit: nvm, there's a missing `'` at the end of line 2, before the closing colon.

Comment: My mistake. I've modified the answer to handle the syntax error :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.setInterval` and a boolean with the current status

```js
const underscore = document.getElementById('flashingUnderscore');
var displayed = true;
function flash() {
  if(displayed) {
    underscore.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    underscore.style.display = 'block';
  }
  displayed = !displayed;
}
window.setInterval(flash, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="flashingUnderscore">_</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  var yourDiv = document.getElementById('flashingUnderscore');
  if(yourDiv.style.visibility == "visible")
        yourDiv.style.visibility == "hidden")
  else
        yourDiv.style.visibility == "visible")
}, 1000);
```

The other solutions change the display value, however that may change the layout if it was taking up space. visibility will just hide it.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use css as an animation:

```css
@keyframes blinking {
    0% {
       opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
#flashingUnderscore{
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  animation:blinking .3s infinite;
/*    animation-name: blinking;
  animation-duration: 2s; */
}
```

```html
<p>Hello<span id="flashingUnderscore">_</span>there</p>
```